# Add css class name with a TS property Angular 7

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, angular7

I'm having an issue with a simple thing I guess ...

I just need my `span` tag to have a class named store in a variable from my `.ts file`:

`<span [ngClass]="{'flag-icon': true, 'my_property_in_TS': true}"></span>`

I tried some things like this :

`<span [ngClass]="{'flag-icon': true, ${lang.codeIcon}: true}"></span>`

`<span [ngClass]="{'flag-icon': true, lang.codeIcon: true}"></span>`

I'm sure the answer is very simple... Does someone knows how to make it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try something like this -

```
<span [ngClass]="['flag-icon', lang.codeIcon]"></span>
```

For more ways -

- [Angular -NgClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)

Comment: Oh god I knew this was so simple .. Thank you @Pardeep !

Answer (score 3):

To use the css class stored in `lang.codeIcon`, do like that:

```
<span [ngClass]="lang.codeIcon"></span>
```

For many classes, use an array:

```
<span [ngClass]="[lang.codeIcon, 'flag-icon']"></span>
```

For conditionnal, use braces:

```
<span [ngClass]="{'flag-icon': booleanVar, lang.codeIcon: !booleanVar}"></span>
```